# In excel how would I create a VLOOKUP that searches words that are subsets of other words I need to search?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I want to create a vlookup but am confused about how to do it for this case.

I want to tie "fish" to a word, and also "fish2" to another word. But how to do a vlookup on a set of data like the two tables below ? When searching for "fish" I don't want to include anything else, such as "fish2" .

any tips appreciated, thanks

[image: excelVlookupEg]
[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRXwp.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRXwp.png)

Comment: What do you want to do after search? What the problem you are facing to search?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the desired result? What is the input? What is the result? What is the logic that leads to the result? Your screenshot does not have that.

Comment: The key is to use wildcards like in [this article](https://exceljet.net/formula/partial-match-with-vlookup)